# Cannot Create a Signature in Outlook 07

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-2007, microsoft-office

I deployed Office 07 around the company and one user is not able to make a signature. I found that when he clicks on the signature button the window does not come up. Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was an issue with the roaming profile. I backed up his profile, and then rebuilt it for him. after that I was able to get into the signature window at set everything up.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just one user I'd run the [**Office Diagnostics tool**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/detect-and-repair-applications-in-microsoft-office-2007/) (Start \ Programs \ Microsoft Office \ Microsoft Office Tools \ Microsoft Office Diagnostics).  If that doesn't do it try just reinstalling Outlook.

Comment: I gave that a try but it did not provide much information unfortunately.